# Random Sample Validation

Tags: probability, sampling, validation

This is a real life scenario where I have just assumed responsibility for a new team

The results of my  team who perform legal contract abstractions are audited each month by our client using random sampling - the results have major ramifications.

Mth Contract Population 483

Client Random Sample    40

Number of Type XX contracts in above Population 3

Q: What is the probability that all 3 Type XX contracts were included in the client's "random" sample?

Please could the formula also be provided just so I can perform analysis on previous monthly samples in case this was simply extremely bad luck!

Comment: Because there are no apparently sensitive materials here, deletion of the text amounts to vandalism of the thread--and it doesn't actually remove the information, which anybody can review by looking at the edit history. Therefore I rolled this question back to its previous version. If you think that any aspect of your post reveals sensitive information, then please flag it and explain why.  Moderators are able to respond by making permanent redactions to protect information like inadvertent revelation of passwords, etc.

Comment: Unusual events do occur by chance ("bad luck"), but I think this is the wrong question.   Your attention would have been drawn to *any* unusual event. So the correct question is: what is the probability of any "unusual" event, not just the one that happend to occur. It's not easy to define "unusual", but it's a large set: 1) all population occurrences of any contract type were picked; 2) for types with lots of occurrences, all but one (or two) were picked; 3)No occurrences of types with lots of occurrences were picked

Comment: If contracts are ordered by date in a month 4) none in the first (second, third, fourth) week were picked;  none in the first or second week were picked (choose any combination). 6) Only "large" contracts were picked; 7) only "small ones"; 8) only new ones; 9) only old ones; 10) contracts serviced by one of your staff were not picked.  I think that you can think of more events that would have surprised you. Thus, the probability of being surprised will be much higher than the probability well  calculated by @dsaxton.

Answer (score 5):

There are a total of $\binom{483}{40}$ equally likely ways of selecting $40$ items from the $483$, where $\binom{n}{k} = n! / k! (n - k)!$.  The number of samples that contain all $3$ type XX contracts is the number of ways of selecting the remaining $37$ items from the $480$ non-XX contracts or $\binom{480}{37}$, since there is exactly one combination including all $3$ type XX contracts for each of these samples.  So the probability you're seeking is

\begin{align}
\frac{\binom{480}{37}}{\binom{483}{40}} \cong 0.0005 .
\end{align}